# react - how to correctly use event.preventDefault? Should it be used on <button> onClick?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm confused after reading the documentation for both react and some HTML stuff about how on click event handling should work.

For buttons, for example a button that onClick will dispatch an action to submit a form, is a `preventDefault` necessary?

Thanks

Comment: if all the answers are really helpful, do I need to pick a check mark?  THey are ALL helpful :( . sorry

Comment: Select any of the answers provided. It works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `event.preventDefault()` method stops the default action of an element from happening.

In your case, prevent a submit button from submitting a form.
Another example - prevent a link from following the URL.

So it is preferred to use it on onClick method. It'll stop a form from automatically submitting the form.

Answer (score 2):

e.preventDefault is used when you want to stop actual action of thing.

Eg: Form submission 
You want to work on that so use e.preventDefault and form will not submit as if it automatically submit with submit button then data will go in url which you do not want.

Also for checking validation during form submission.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('The link was clicked.');
  }
```

preventDefault is not that much necessary
if you want then just make a function above add preventDefault in that and call that function in button OnClick